# C#. Не работает update записи в событии CellEndEdit после очистки ячейки

Tags: c#, sql

Описала в этом событии update записей в таблице БД.
Работает, если редактируя ячейку я ввожу какое-нибудь значение. Если очищу ячейку, то это событие не вызывается. А мне нужно сделать update с пустым значением. Как правильно сделать update записи с пустой ячейкой?

```
    private void dGV_view_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(dGV_view.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        string DtProv = dGV_view.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.Parse(DtProv);
        DtProv = parsedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        int Count1 = Convert.ToInt32(dGV_view.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
        int Count2 = Convert.ToInt32(dGV_view.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
        string Prim = dGV_view.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        connect();
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "update provDoc set DtEdit = '" + dnow + "', DtProv = '" + DtProv + "', Count1 = '" + Count1 + "', Count2 = '" + Count2 + "', Prim = '" + Prim + "' where id = " + id;
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Какую именно ячейку? `Convert.ToInt32` и `DateTime.Parse` для пустого значения выкинут исключение.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, типа string

Comment: Какая именно ячейка по номеру? 4? Значение которой присваивается в Prim? | И что именно происходит: в самом деле _не вызывается событие_ или запрос не выполняется?

Comment: @Nataka, скажите хоть какая ошибка?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ячейка 4, событие не вызывается, если очищу эту ячейку

Comment: @Yaroslav, ошибки нет

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit?view=netframework-4.7.2